# My game on Steam [PoL] requires Internet Explorer 9

Tags: software-installation, internet, steam, playonlinux

I am trying to play a game on Steam that requires Internet Explorer 9. Is there any way to do this on PlayOnLinux. I've tried to make a non-listed install on PoL, but Steam afterwards does not detect it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This one would be impossible. Last time I checked,

[Internet Explorer 9](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23216) [does not want](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19679) [to play nice](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23214) [with WINE](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23215).

Unless you can find a way to hack it, not possible. Sorry.

Comment: Well, the truth is, that IE9 doesn't need to work, the game uses some parts of the code of the installed copy of IE9 (this have some reference with HTML5), so all I need is to install it. But sadly, the only package I can see is for the IE8.

Comment: Programs can't access the direct code. They can access APIs. IE9 can't be installed period on Wine/PoL. Thus, no API exists.